# An application of Weierstrass theorem for holomorphic functions

Tags: holomorphic-functions

We have the following theorem for holomorphic functions.

> **Theorem** (Weierstrass)
>
> If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions on an open set $U\subset\mathbb C$ such that $(f_n)$ tends uniformly to $f$ on every compact $K\Subset U$.
>
> Then $f$ is also holomorphic and $({f_n}^{(k)})$ tends  uniformly to $f^{(k)}$ for all $k$.

I would like to have a simple concrete application (without meromorphic functions, infinite products  and elliptic functions) of this theorem if you know one. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A corollary of Weierstraß' theorem is that for every normal family $\mathscr{F}\subset \mathscr{O}(U)$ (where normality is $\mathbb{C}$-normality, i.e. we don't allow sequences converging locally uniformly to $\infty$), the family

$$\mathscr{F}^{(k)} = \{ f^{(k)} : f \in \mathscr{F}\}$$

of $k^{\text{th}}$ derivatives is again normal.

This fact is occasionally useful ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385487/a-family-of-analytic-functions-that-map-to-the-open-unit-disk), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386036/let-f-be-such-that-f0-0-and-f0-1-find-iff-conditions-for-normality-o), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761228/why-a-holomorphic-function-satisfying-these-conditions-has-to-be-linear)).

Comment: Thanks, though I'm looking for a more concrete example if possible. Your third link is very interesting nonetheless.

Comment: We can use the theorem to prove that a power series is holomorphic on its disk of convergence. Though that can also be proven by calculations with power series and elementary estimates. It's more interesting if we take a locally uniformly convergent series of holomorphic functions, but the main application of that that I can think of now is the Mittag-Leffler theorem, and you didn't want meromorphic functions.

Comment: @Yes indeed, because I'm reading a small course on the subject and meromorphic functions only come later. I'll keep looking for a concrete example, and if I find one I'll post it here.

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774775/holomorphic-function-is-bijective-if-neutral-fixed-point) is similar to the third link, you may find it interesting too. I'll think about further (different) applications and add them to the answer if I find an interesting one.